# The Internet Just Disappeared on its own [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS]

Tags: networking, internet, 20.04, ethernet, vmware

Using an Ubuntu VM on VMWare. The internet just stopped working out of the blue and even experts don't know why.

Some stats:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

---

```
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: ens33
       version: 01
       serial: 00:0c:29:d7:ef:66
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=no mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fd5c0000-fd5dffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:fd500000-fd50ffff
```

---

Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065042) , [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049302/wired-ethernet-not-working-ubuntu-18-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547863/ethernet-and-wireless-networking-disabled-ubuntu-14-04-1-lts-server) (from this forum)

Can't find `ifup` and `ifdown` commands installed

[settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWLN8.png)

I also reset the network settings on my VMWare but that was of no help.

It is very urgent and I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: I've tried the above things (posted in the links above) and there aren't any error messages I can get. The internet simply doesn't connect nor is it visible in the settings. Is there any diagnostic command you'd want me to run and give you the output of ? Cause the output above is all I know about. @Nmath

Comment: your host OS may not be sharing the connection correctly.  I think this is more of a problem with configuring your VM than it is with Ubuntu itself.  Does this help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/89353/network-disabled

Comment: That seems unlikely cause it was working before perfectly on the default settings and I even reset the network settings. Either way I have done the steps in the link you shared above earlier and it didn't resolve it

Comment: The solution here is what worked finally
https://askubuntu.com/a/1010564/1095377